# Showing that a subspace is dense

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T \in \mathcal L(\ell^2(\mathbb C))$,
so that
$$
T(x_n) = \left(\frac{x_n}{n}\right)\,.
$$
Show that the range $\mathcal R(T)$ is a dense subspace, knowing that the spectrum $\sigma(T) = \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ and a point spectrum $\sigma_p(T) = \sigma(T) \setminus \{0\}$.

We also know that
$$
\mathcal R(T) = S := \left\{(y_n) \in \ell^2(\mathbb C) \mid \sum_n n^2 |y_n|^2 < \infty\right\}\,.
$$

**Hint:** The dense subspace of finite sequences $\ell^{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb C)$ might be useful.

### An attempt

We know that the range of $T$ is a subspace, as $T0_{\ell^2} = 0_{\ell^2} / n = 0_{\ell^2}$, and for $x, y \in \ell^2(\mathbb C)$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$, we have

\begin{align}
\sum_n n^2 \left| T(\alpha  x_n + \beta y_n)\right|^2
&= \sum_n n^2 \left| \frac \alpha n  x_n + \frac\beta n y_n) \right|^2 \\
&= \sum_n \left| \alpha  x_n + \beta y_n\right|^2 < \infty\,,
\end{align}
as $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$ is its own subspace.

As for density, let $y \in \ell^2(\mathbb C)$, so
$$
\sum_k |y_k|^2 < \infty.
$$
 We know that for a converging series the tail approaches zero starting from some large enough $n$, which leads to $\ell^{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb C)$, the set of sequences whose tail is zero, being dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$ and $\mathcal R(T)$. As density is transitive, $\mathcal R(T)$ is a subspace of $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$ and $\ell^{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb C)$, then $\mathcal R(T)$ has to be dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$ as well.

Did I get the gist of this right, or am I missing something crucial?

Comment: I'm not sure what your argument for density is. What you want to show is, that $\ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq R(T)$.

Comment: Which by transitivity then forces $\mathcal R(T) $ to be dense in $\ell^2$ as well...

Comment: Yes, that is fine. How do you show that $\ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq R(T)$?

Comment: Well, every finite sequence converges and is $p$-summable, so they would automatically be in the set $S = \mathcal R (T)$.

Comment: this shows that any finite sequence $x$ is in $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$. How do you know that there is an element $y \in \ell^2(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $Ty = x$.

Comment: Also, transitivity is not at play here. What you want to use is that the closure operator is montone and that $\ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\ell^1(\mathbb{C})$ i.e. that $\overline{\ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C})} \subseteq \ell^{2}(\mathbb{C})$. Because if then we can show that $R(T) \subseteq \ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C})$ we get $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{C}) = \overline{\ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C})} \subseteq \overline{T(R)} \subseteq \ell^2 (\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: So what I need to do is show that an arbitrary finite sequence can be mapped to from $\ell^2$. Couldn't I just take a finite sequence multiplied by $n$ from $\ell^2$ to get a sequence without the coefficient $n$ in $\ell^{\mathrm{fin}}$?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. The cleanest way would be to give an explicit preimage of any $x \in \ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C})$. As you have noted, for any $x \in \ell^{fin}(\mathbb{C})$, the element $y \in \ell^{2}(\mathbb{C})$ defined by $y_n := n x_n$ does the job.

Answer (score 1):

For the fast answer you'll just need to recall some facts about the spectrum of a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space:

- firstly, $\ell^2 (\mathbb{C})$ is a Hilbert space
- the spectrum of a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space is comprised of the point spectrum, the continuous spectrum and the residue spectrum.
- For a normal operator, the residue spectrum is empty. The operator $T$ is even self adjoint.

Now, you know that $\sigma(T) = \{1/n \vert n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ and $\sigma_p(T) =  \{1/n \vert n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. In other words, the continuous spectrum is $\{0\}$ and thus you know that $0I - T = T$ is a injective but not surjective and has dense image, which means that $R(T)$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I would like to say this was useful, but this little exercise was a part of a larger guided exercise where we show that $\sigma_c(T) = {0}$, so I can hardly use all of these facts.

Comment: Fair enough. I hope the comments are helpful though

Comment: I would say yes, they were.